Adding Fields in an existing Parameter PBI
After I added mt fields parameters, I am unable to find a way to go back to that editor view to rearrange or add new fields.
[Would love to get back to this view with my existing parameters] (https://i.sstatic.net/LhZfWY5d.png)
I kept making small mistakes, recreating parameters from step 1 gets really annoying
I am new to parameters, there has got to be a easier way to this. I'm the only that uses power bi in my company so no one can help me here lol.
Edit Parameters greyed out

Those are two different types of Parameters.
The first one is Field (or Numeric) Parameters and are for the report side of things. The second one is for Power Query parameters, for setting values to Power Query.
Granted you cannot use the UI to edit Field Parameters, however it is relatively easy to manually edit by click on the its table then updating the DAX. It would look similar to:
Parameter = {
    ("A", NAMEOF('Table'[A]), 0),
    ("B", NAMEOF('Table'[B]), 1)
}

Edit a field parameter
